# "Open containing folder" hotkey in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: macros, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2012

In versions of Visual Studio before 2012, I was able to create a hotkey to perform "Open Containing Folder" for the current active text file. I accomplished this by creating a macro that had a keystroke assigned to it.

Visual Studio 2012 does not have macros. How would I accomplish the above in this version?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately you'll now need to download the VSSDK and create a VSPackage to do that, now that macros have been dropped from the IDE.

[The closest thing to a macro now is a PowerShell script](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2012/03/30/using-nuget-powershell-to-replace-missing-macros-in-dev-11.aspx), which you could run from the console but I'm not aware of any way to assign a keyboard shortcut to it.

Running PS outside of the IDE is an option (via an External Tool command with a keyboard shortcut configured), but obtaining the EnvDTE outside of process could be complicated.

**EDIT:** There is a much simpler solution. I can't believe I didn't realise it to begin with!

Simply go into *Tools... Options... Environment... Keyboard*  locate `File.OpenContainingFolder` and assign a shortcut. This command will open the active document's containing folder.

Comment: Interesting. I had tried the same thing in VS10 in the past and it didn't work. It seems to be working now.

Comment: I now remember why I created th macro. When opening containing folder with File.OpenContainingFolder, the column header is selected (most of the time). With the macro it defaults to selecting the correct file in the file list.

Comment: I'd be happy to create the VSPackage for you if you can post the macro code.

Comment: Thank you. We will be officially migrating to VS11 in a couple weeks. I may take you up on your offer.

Answer (score 7):

I found a keyboard shortcut for **Open Containing Folder**: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>

When you press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> it opens `Tab Context Menu` Then you see that the shortcut key for ***O***pen Containing Folder is **O** key, then you should press **O**.

[image: Menu]

Comment: I don't see that key being assigned anywhere. I expect that it's mapped to `File.OpenContainingFolder`, which is described in a different answer here.

Comment: @GaTechThomas you're right but it doesn't need to assign to `File.OpenContainingFolder` because it is a default keyboardshortcut in visual studio. Just test and you'll see that it works.

Comment: I did test it. What version of VS and keyboard profile are you using?

Comment: @GaTechThomas I use VS 2015 Update 3 and  'Visual C# 2005' keyboard scheme.